# Prevent component from re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a beginners problem in react. I'm aware that there is probably an explanation for this out there, but I've been trying for two days with no luck. So here we go. I have made this navigation bar:
[image]

As you can see the menu closes every time navigation is used. The following code is responsible for navigation:

```
const OnClickNav = (index: string, dispatch) => {

  const runValidations = null;
  dispatch(FormLayoutActions.updateCurrentView({ newView: index, runValidations }));
};
```

I would like the menu to stay open after the navigation function is run, but the state variable "mounted" is always reset to `false`. Here you can see the code for that:

```
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
```

So what happens is that dispatch is run and the state variable is set to `false`. I would like it to stay with value "true" after navigating, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Add more code. Where is the `useState` present? Where is `mounted` used? When do you want the nav to compress?

Answer (score 0):

`useState` has nothing to do with redux and is not directly influenced by your dispatch, it's component local state.
If your component gets remounted (which I assume is happening here, but you didn't add the code for that), the component state will be reset.

I also assume you have multiple pages with a duplicated menu each?

Either way, moving your `mounted` state (maybe call it `isMenuOpen` or something like that) into the redux state should solve your problem.
It will be independent of the mounting of components.
But then you'll have to create a reducer and fire an event for closing the menu.